# SQL, when adding a field to database put in two fields and modify

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this database setup:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b2989

I want to add a record called "solrID" under item where I already have "ID".

Is it possible to have SQL setup so whenever an entry gets put into ID I also add the same value into SOLRID, except I start it with the text "app".

Therefore, when I add a record to my "item" table, ID autoincrements to have a value of say "**2**" then *I want SOLRID to automatically have the value "**app2**".*

Is this possible?

Comment: That's where you set up a foreign key. Then `On insert` do the update of foreign key :)

Comment: Ah, I've never heard of a foreign key. I'll google it

Comment: Just add a UPDATE to the query:

UPDATE DatabaseName
   SET [SOLRID ] = ('app'+[ID])
GO

Comment: `O.o well yeah please Google. In the mean time, also check on how to create insert/update trigger and cursors :) @AceAlfred how about if he is inserting one huge bulk of records?

Comment: If you can do it in the original insert of data that is probably better.
--need to have all the other columns as well..
INSERT INTO DatabaseName
           ([SOLRID]
     VALUES
           (('app'+[ID]))

What is one huge bulk of records defined as??

Comment: The database is set to autoincrement so I cant do a seperate operation on the key I dont think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices that comes to mind is create a view that creates solrID on the fly, or if you really want to have a column that stores what is basically redundant data you can use a trigger to populate solrID.

For me, knowing only what I know from your message I would consider using a view unless you have a really reason to store solrID in the actual table.